# programatically how to get fieldcollection item by passing fieldcollection id?

Tags: entities

Retrieve field_collection item as field-set format by passing id. I have only field_collection id. I want to retrieve field-collection form by passing field id.

Comment: Hello and welcome. If you meant [Field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection), it might be better to use either full name "Field collection" or machine name "field_collection", and link to module to avoid misunderstandings. Just saying. Remember you can always edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do like this...

```
$nid = 49;
$node = node_load($nid);
// Renders total node with your field collection items.
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

// Let's use field_test_collection is your collection item and field_test_collection_title, field_test_collection_desc are your couple of fields under it.
// Iterate through each item from field_test_collection.
foreach($wrapper->field_test_collection as $i){
  // Title is here.
  $title = $i->field_test_collection_title->value();
  // Description is here.
  $desc = $i->field_test_collection_desc->value();
  print $title . '<br>';
  print $desc . '<br>';
}
```

and

check out this link [Entity API](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/7). It may help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`field_collection_item_load()`](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/misc/field_collection--field_collection.module/function/field_collection_item_load/7.x), e.g.

```
$item = field_collection_item_load($item_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could also be achieved with the following code.

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', FIELD_COLLECTION_ID/FIELD_COLLECTION_OBJECT);
```